# Remove ?m=1 query string from url using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, query-string, blogger

I switch over from blogger to wordpress a while back and I'm trying to figure out the right way to simply strip the ?m=1 query string from my urls that blogger used to ad in for mobile redirect

Answer (score 3):

Give this a try:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} m=1
RewriteRule (.*) /$1? [R=301, L]
```

This should be inserted above all your other rules, or just below `RewriteEngine On`.

Answer (score 2):

Add following code before the mod_rewrite rule in your htaccess file and save it.

Note! Replace your domain with yourdomain in this rule.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^(s|p)=.*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*wp-admin.*
RewriteRule .* http://www.yourdomain.com%{REQUEST_URI}? [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```